# jquery load , cant get body only

Tags: jquery

trying to pull the body content , and its not working , but if i pull the entire url it works fine

This works to grab the entire page

```
$(function(){
        $('#siteloader').load('http://www26.myfantasyleague.com/2015/ajax_ld?L=25902');
});
```

But i just want the content of the body and using the bodyID it doesnt work

```
$(function(){
        $('#siteloader').load('http://www26.myfantasyleague.com/2015/ajax_ld?L=25902 #body_ajax_ld');
});
```

Comment: Any errors on the console ? @MShack

Comment: Try loading it inside a div than in the `<body>` directly.